# Select specific td's with no id or classes

Tags: html, css

I have a got a table with  3 rows and 3 table data cells.

Select first tr, first td, and all b tags from it:

`tr + td b {}`

Select second tr, second td, and all b tags from it:

`tr+tr > td+td b {}`

I am trying to select them without `nth-child` because IE8 and earlier don't support it.

Can anybody fix those selectors for me, because I think I'm doing it wrong and it's not selecting them properly.

Comment: just test it with all browser, if that worked well it will work well and you are not wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) work in **IE8**, use it like:

```
tr:first-child+tr    -> tr:nth-child(2)
tr:first-child+tr+tr -> tr:nth-child(3)
```

---

> Select first `tr`, first `td`, and all `b` tags from it:

```
tr:first-child td:first-child b {}
```

---

> Select second `tr`, second `td`, and all `b` tags from it:

```
tr:first-child+tr td:first-child+td b {}
```

---

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FPA7/2/)

Or you can use some JS utility like [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

Answer (score -2):

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var i=0;
  $("table").find("tr").each(function(){
  alert($(this).find("td:eq("+i+")").find("b").length);
  });

  });
  </script>
```

You will get the count of each  in each row. For example 1st tr: 1st td and  in first td. Then 2nd tr, 2nd td and  in 2nd td and so on. Let me know if it solve your problem.